Getting undefined values on submission of form that is created using shadcn and zustand
I am using react, RHF with shadcn to create a multi step form. I have created a customInput, customRadio and customSelect component for rendering the html form inputs. I am seeing that defaultValues are being set and even the input fields are reflecting changes. However, on submission, I am seeing 2 issues:

the changed input fields are becoming undefined.
radio field is saving string instead of boolean even though defaultValue is boolean false

TemplateDefaults.jsx
const TemplateDefaults = () => {

  const getStepCount = useFormStore(state => state.currentStep)
  const FORMPART_NAME = STEPS_TO_STEP_NAMES[getStepCount];
  const templateData = useFormStore(state => state.formData[FORMPART_NAME])
  const {templateDetailsDefault} = baseDefaults
  
  const form = useForm({
    defaultValues: templateData || templateDetailsDefault
  });
  const {reset} = form

  useEffect(() => {
    if (templateData) {
      reset(templateData); // Reset the form when templateData changes
      
    }
  }, [templateData]);

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log("submitted -> ",data)
  }

  return (
    <Form {...form}>
      <form className="flex flex-col" onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <details
          open
          className="group flex flex-col overflow-auto mb-8 border border-blue-200 rounded-md w-[96%] mx-auto"
        >
          <summary className="cursor-pointer px-6 py-2 bg-blue-100 text-blue-800">
            <span>{templateData[0].heading}</span>
          </summary>
          <div className="px-6 py-3 grid grid-cols-4 gap-5">

            <CustomInput
              fullPath={`[0].name`}
              control={form.control}
              label="Name"
            /> 
            <CustomSelect
              apiFieldValue="subject"
              fullPath={`[0].subject`}
              control={form.control}
              label="subject"
              defaultArray={templateDetailsDefault[0].subject}
            />
            <CustomRadio
              fullPath={`[0].templateStatus`}
              condensedRadio
              control={form.control}
              label="Template Status"
            />       
            
          </div>
        </details>
        ...
        <Button type="submit">save</Button>
      </form>
    </Form>
  );
};

export default TemplateDefaults`

CustomInput.jsx
const CustomInput = ({
    defaultArray,
    fullPath,
    control,
    label,
    defaultValues,
    ...others
  }) => {
    const { disable } = others;
    
    const renderInput = ({field}) => {
 
        return (
        <FormItem className="flex flex-col justify-between" >
            {label && <FormLabel className="max-w-[75%]">{label}</FormLabel>}
            <FormControl>
            <Input 
              disabled={disable}
              {...field} 
              value={field.value ?? ""} 
            />
            </FormControl>
            <FormMessage />
        </FormItem>
        );
    }

    return (
      <FormField
        name={fullPath}
        control={control}
        render={renderInput}
      />        
    )
  }

I tried to implement the changes manually but this also didn't work
...
const renderInput = ({field}) => {
      const handleChange = (e) => {
        setValue(fullPath, e.target.value);  
        field.onChange(e);  
      };
        return (
        <FormItem className="flex flex-col justify-between" >
            {label && <FormLabel className="max-w-[75%]">{label}</FormLabel>}
            <FormControl>
            <Input 
              disabled={disable}
              {...field} 
              value={field.value ?? ""} 
              onChange={handleChange}
              />
...

Any suggestions regarding this would be greatly appreciated
